# Procura um arquivo e retornar o caminho desse arquivo

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Estou tentando fazer a busca de um Arquivo e quando encontrar quero que retorne a mensagem Rota do Arquivo é: "E:\Projetos\Arquivo.txt" por exemplo.
Eu já sei como fazer a busca do arquivo, mas não sei como retornar a rota completa do arquivo pesquisado. alguém sabe me dizer como fazer isso?

Eu já tentei desse modo mais não vai como eu quero.
achei esse código na internet.

```
function TDMG.ProcuraArquivo(const cPath, cFile: String): String;
var
  Path : String;
  S: String;
  nRet: Integer;
  Search: TSearchRec;
begin
  nRet := FindFirst(cPath+'*.*', faAnyFile or faArchive or faDirectory, Search);
  while nRet = 0 do
  begin
    if (Trim(Search.Name) <> '.') and (Trim(Search.Name) <> '..') then
    begin
      { Se for um diretório, chama a função para percorrê-lo. }
      if Search.Attr and faDirectory > 0 then
        ProcuraArquivo(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(cPath+Search.Name), cFile)
      { Neste caso estamos fazendo uma busca exata, pode-se fazer um if com pos
        para buscar extensões partes do nome e etc. }
      else if Trim(Search.Name) = cFile then
        Path := cPath+Search.Name;
    end;
    nRet := FindNext(Search);
  end;
  Result := Path;
end;
```

Eu estou procurando colocando C: no parâmetro 'cPath' e o nome do arquivo em 'cFile' ele até acha mais não para quando acha e quando para não retorna com a rota do arquivo para eu por na Msg.

Comment: Me parece que está faltando colocar o retorno do `ProcuraArquivo` na if  que checa se é diretório, assim `Path:= ProcuraArquivo(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(cPath+Search.Name), cFile)`, pois assim vai ser atribuido posteriormente para `Result := Path;` com o valor da recursão.

Answer (score 1):

Se você usa faAnyFile não precisa incluir faArchive or faDirectory.

Ao comparar o nome do arquivo que está procurando com os do diretório use StrIComp. Assim a busca fica não sensitiva a maiúsculas/minúsculas.

Para interromper a busca e retornar o caminho com o nome do arquivo, use a variável Path.

Então, a sugestão seria assim:

```
function TFormMain.ProcuraArquivo(const cPath, cFile: String): String;
var
  Path : String;
  S: String;
  nRet: Integer;
  Search: TSearchRec;
begin
  Path := '';
  nRet := FindFirst(cPath+'*.*', faAnyFile, Search);
  while (nRet = 0) and (Path = '') do
  begin
    if (Search.Name <> '.') and (Search.Name <> '..') then
    begin
      { Se for um diretório, chama a função para percorrê-lo. }
      if Search.Attr and faDirectory > 0 then
        Path := ProcuraArquivo(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(cPath+Search.Name), cFile)
      { Neste caso estamos fazendo uma busca exata, pode-se fazer um if com pos
        para buscar extensões partes do nome e etc. }
      else if (StrIComp(PChar(Search.Name), PChar(cFile)) = 0) then
        Path := cPath+Search.Name;
    end;
    nRet := FindNext(Search);
  end;
  Result := Path;
end;
```